# EditorFor htmlAttributes not working for type bool (MVC 5.2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

Since MVC 5.1 it is possible to add html attributes to editor templates as follows:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "fooId", @class="fooClass" } })
```

If property `Foo` is of type `string`, it will generate the input markup correctly, including the custom attributes.

But if property `Foo` is of type `bool` (or `bool?`) the attributes are ignored...

Am I missing something here?. Could it be that this feature is still not supported for templates that generates "select" markup?

Comment: Are you sure? For me everything works fine. All attributes are included for the `bool` properties.

Comment: Yes!. If I simply change the property type to `string` the attribues are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago but I ran into the exact same issue just now. Turns out a different developer had created a Custom Editor Template for Boolean in our solution to be able to customize the text of the drop-down. Your code is supposed to work for editors out of the box but it does not work automatically for custom editors ... you have to implement it yourself.

If this is your issue, you need to modify the Custom Editor Template to fetch htmlAttributes out of ViewData and pass them along to the underlying DropDownListFor (or whatever helper you are using). Here is what my Custom Editor Template looks like now:

```
@model bool?
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@{
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model,
        new List<SelectListItem>(3) { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Unknown", Value = "" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value }
    }, htmlAttributes)
}
```

The credit for this explanation & solution goes to https://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes